# How to merge/layer two audio files using Python AudioSegment without it breaking the wav header

Tags: python, audio, layer, pydub, audiosegment

I am more or less following the code below to merge two audio files. It mostly works, where audio segment can export both the original files and the combined file to a folder. These play fine in finder (Mac). However, when brought into a music app like Ableton, the waveform is distorted and sounds like digital garbage. I have a feeling this is because this code is messing with the wav header.

I have also noted the combined sound is showing a bitrate of 32 in the finder file info, whereas I am specifically outputting it as bitrate='24'

Any theories?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file("1.wav", format="wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_file("2.wav", format="wav")

# Overlay sound2 over sound1 at position 0
overlay = sound1.overlay(sound2, position=0)


# simple export
file_handle = overlay.export("output.wav", format="wav", bitrate='24')
```

[image]

Comment: can you post a sound file example (input and output)? i don't think the header is the problem. when you combine 2 sounds it is very likely that they will add up and be too loud. if the file is 32 bit it has enough headroom to handle the volume, but if it is imported and converted to 24 bit, it might be clipped. you could try to lower the volume of the 2 segments before combining them, and see wether the issue disappears. are you using PyDub with FFMPEG?

Answer (score 1):

Note to others, I solved this by moving to using Sox (or PySox) instead of AudioSegment, which seams to work much more reliably with all the features I was looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).